# Adding a 'Which branch?' field to work items in TFS

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, tfs, alm

Suppose that you are part of a Scrum team that is using the Scrum Team Project template in Visual Studio and the 'Advanced Branch Plan', as prescribed by the Visual Studio ALM Rangers. Your team develops a product, called FooBar, until you've completed all the features and testing you plan on doing for a particular release (we'll call the release FooBar v1). The development branch is merged with the main branch, and the relevant branches for the 'Advanced Branch Plan' are branched from the main branch.

Eventually, FooBar v1 is shipped, and you and your team are hard at work on FooBar v2. Unfortunately, a FooBar v1 customer finds a bug and reports it. A work item is created to fix the bug, but developers need to know where this bug is. Is it in the FooBar v1 Service Pack branch, Development branch, or FooBar v1 Hotfix branch?

Now consider that your team is working on FooBar vN, where N is an arbitrary number. A customer reports a bug in FooBar v(N - M), where M is an arbitrary number and N > M. A work item is created to fix the bug, but developers need to know where this bug is. Is it in FooBar v(N - 1)? Development? FooBar v(N - M + 1)?

Of course, the work item could have a title that indicates which branch the bug resides, but this leads to ad hoc naming schemes that aren't standardized. The best thing would be to add a field when creating a work item that asks which branch the work item relates to. Adding a field to an existing work item type in TFS seems pretty straightforward: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh409273.aspx Unfortunately, this isn't a static list; it's dynamic.

This is a two part question: **1) Is it even possible to add a field to Scrum work items in TFS whose list items are dependent upon branches in a particular team project?**

And: **2) If it is possible, are there any references you could point me towards?** I'd be surprised if this is the first time anyone has ever thought of this...

Comment: All customer releases should come from the same branch. Period! Instead of which branch the bug is in, you should ask the customer to report the *version* the bug is in. Either have control over which versions you release to the customer corresponds to which changeset in TFS, or make the changeset number part of the version, like "major.minor.hotfix.changeset" or similar.

Comment: Note that the above statement must be modified to take major releases into account, but releasing hotfixes out of order for different customers is going to cause you **tons** of problems, only one of which is which changeset that caused it.

Comment: My question was poorly phrased. Our organization is working on product beta releases that our customers can receive (there is Beta1, Beta2, and Beta3). In order to provide support, each beta version has its own Service Pack branch hanging off Main with a Release branch hanging off each one. If a bug is found, the relevant branch is fixed (SPBeta1, SPBeta2, SPBeta3, Dev. This allows us to support all beta versions.) Regardless of our branching strategy, is it possible to add a field to work items whose list items are dependent upon branches in a particular team project?

Comment: Again, you don't distribute branches to customers. You distribute _builds_.

Comment: I promise I'm not trying to be difficult, but I understand that. In the grand scheme (simplified): Main branches Service Pack. Service Pack branches Release. Release is built and shipped. A bug is found. (It _does not matter_ if the customer found it, if a developer found it while developing the next version... all that matters is a bug **somewhere** appeared.) Depending upon where the bug is (shipped product or code still in development), a branch of code will be fixed (it may be built later for _some_ release.) Based on our branching strategy, it can be hard for developers to pinpoint code.

Comment: The question is honestly this: Regardless of our branching strategy and regardless of the type of work item (a bug is an example. This should apply to any work item), is it possible to add a field to work items whose list items are dependent upon branches in a particular team project so that developers can easily find the branch they need develop on when going through their work items? The scope of the question is focused on developers and our branching strategy (which, I know is weird, but it's how we are doing it.)

Comment: Are you missing the fact that if you knew the build, you'd have all the information you need in order to make the fix in the correct branch? What you should strive for is: 1) Have all your assemblies have a version number which equates one to one with the build number (that is, from the version number, you can figure out which build built it), and 2) Then look at the record of the build to see which changesets were built (and this, which branch), which work items, etc.

Comment: Also, to reply to a comment in a way that will notify the person you're replying to, include @JohnSaunders.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a question of which branch the bug is in - it's a question of which *build* the bug is in.

There's a "Found in Build" field for that.

Remember that a build knows which code it built, which work items, which changesets.